# Button click unclick ms-access

Tags: ms-access

In access form, I'm hoping to click on a button and add information to an existing record using an update query.  Ideally, when this happens, the button will change colors and appear 'activated'.

Then, if the user decides that the information that has been added needs to be removed, they can click the same button again.  This removes the previously added information from the table and changes the button appearance to 'inactive'

Comment: What have you tried? What determines if the the information has been added ? Is a field value specific or empty if it has had the information added?

Comment: A button has a `Tag` property which can hold any information you care to give it.  If the value in the `Tag` is TRUE/YES/ACTIVATE then execute one piece of code (and change the Tag value), if it's FALSE/NO/DEACTIVATE then execute another piece of code... or run a query/dlookup to check if the record exists and take appropriate action based on that.

Comment: When the button is clicked, the following code runs:

          DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE Table1 set AddData = 1 WHERE FName ='Tim'"

We are hoping that when it is clicked again, it will remove the '1' from the AddData field.  The code part is the easy part.  I just don't know if it's possible for say the color to be Green when the form opens, but when a user presses the button, the color changes to blue (and stays blue) while there is a 1 in the AddData field.  When the user presses it again, the color goes back to green and the 1 is removed from the AddData field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the colour of a command button if you are using Accesss 2003 or earlier, but you can simulate a button using a label, and obviously you can change a labels caption and colours.

If you are using 2007 on-wards then substitute the Label name to your Command button name.

Using the On_current property of your form use something like

```
If Me.AddData = 1 Then 
    Me.YourLabel.Caption = "Remove Data"
    Me.YourLabel.BackColor = VbRed
Else
    Me.YourLabel.Caption = "Add Data"
    Me.YourLabel.BackColor = VbGreen
End If
```

Then use a similar logic to run your update code from the On_click property of the label, based on the value of AddData.

Comment: You can change the colour of a command button in Access 2010+.

Comment: Ah possibly - I know you couldn't in 2003 and I forget they changed the properties.. My Bad - I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to have `-1` and `0` in AddDate these can be easily converted to `TRUE/FALSE`.

This is taking a few liberties with the info you've given, but it's getting late in the day.

Your form has a command button (`Command7`) and a textbox (`Text8`).
`Text8` has a control source linked to AddData (so it shows -1 or 0).

This code executes whenever you move to a different record.  It checks the value in `Text8` and changes the colour of the command button accordingly:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    With Me
        Select Case .Text8
            Case -1
                .Command7.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case Else
                .Command7.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

This code on the click event of the command button will change the value in Text8 from True to False and vice versa.
It will then requery the form, forcing the `Form_Current` event to fire.
A requery moves the recordset back to the first record, so the bookmark moves it back to the record you were looking at.

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()

    Dim bkmrk As String

    bkmrk = Me.Bookmark
    With Me
        .Text8 = Not CBool(.Text8)
        .Requery
        Me.Bookmark = bkmrk
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
Scrap that -1 and 0 malarkey....

- Change the `Select Case` to `Case 1` in the `Form_Current` event.
- Change the `.Text8 = Not CBool(.Text8)` in the `Command7_Click` event to
  `.Text8 = Abs(Not CBool(.Text8 * (-1)))`